# Facing issue compiling GWT after upgrading java to java11

Tags: gwt

Getting following exception after upgrading java. I am using gwt 2.9 libraries and ant in our project.

```
[java]    Ignored 37 units with compilation errors in first pass.
     [java] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
     [java]    Resolving com.google.gwt.cell.client.FieldUpdater
     [java]       Found type 'com.google.gwt.cell.client.FieldUpdater'
     [java]          [ERROR] Unable to find class java/lang/Object
     [java]          [ERROR] Unable to find class java/lang/Object
     [java]          [ERROR] Unable to find class java/lang/Object
     [java]    Resolving com.google.gwt.cell.client.ValueUpdater
     [java]       Found type 'com.google.gwt.cell.client.ValueUpdater'
     [java]          [ERROR] Unable to find class java/lang/Object
     [java]          [ERROR] Unable to find class java/lang/Object
     [java]    Resolving com.google.gwt.core.client.AsyncProvider
     [java]       Found type 'com.google.gwt.core.client.AsyncProvider'
     [java]          [ERROR] Unable to find class java/lang/Object
     [java]          [ERROR] Unable to find class java/lang/Object
     [java]          [ERROR] Unable to find class java/lang/Object
     [java]          Resolving method get
     [java]             Found type 'com.google.gwt.core.client.Callback'
     [java]                [ERROR] Unable to find class java/lang/Object
     [java]                [ERROR] Unable to find class java/lang/Object
     [java]                [ERROR] Unable to find class java/lang/Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest gwt libraries (gwt-user-2.9.0.jar,gwt-dev-2.9.0.jar,gwt-servlet-2.9.0.jar) depends on following jars. After adding these jars in project issue got fixed.

ant.jar
colt-1.2.0.jar
asm-7.1.jar
jsinterop-annotations-2.8.2-v20191108.jar
base-1.0.0-beta-2.jar
tapestry-util-text-4.0.2.jar

Answer (score 1):

If something as fundamental as `java.lang.Object` is not available to the GWT compiler, it sounds like the `gwt-user` dependency is not available to the compiler.  This jar library contains the JRE emulation classes.

Make sure `gwt-user-2.9.0.jar` is on the classpath when ant runs the GWT compiler.

Comment: gwt-user-2.9.0.jar is available on the classpath, but still facing the same issue. Exception stack trace is very lengthy so copied only first few lines. At the end of the stack trace I could see following error message   ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/projects/watch4net/APGv2/libs/gwt-user-2.9.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/emul/java/lang/RuntimeException.java'                                               
looks like some issue with the jar file